# Is there a best practice guide for testing Drive apps?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm finding it difficult to properly develop, test, stage and publish my Drive app. As an example of the sort of problems I'm facing, when I configure my app in the Api Console, I need to specify a single URL for 'open from drive'. Obviously I can't change that without impacting live users. So I'm kinda concluding that I need to register multiple copies of my app., one for each stage of development, testing and deployment.

Has anybody gone through this process and developed a set of best practice guidelines?

Comment: Have you found any useful techniques?

Comment: several ;-)
If I get chance I'll write a Q&A
Are you having and specific problems?

Comment: Awesome! All the problems, I guess: do we need to create a new drive file for all of our automated tests? How do we authenticate a test user automatically? Is there a way to simulate a user losing access to a file mid-test?

Comment: It kind of seems like Google expects us to deploy different versions of the app for testing, QA, etc, each with different keys.  Is this what you did?

Comment: Ultimately, yes. I wasted a lot of time following the Google provided examples Which have hard-coded app-ids and Oauth URLs. Once I made all of these variable depending on the execution environment, things went a lot smoother. So eg. instead of getting the OAuth callback URL from a file, I now have a static method which returns an appropriate URL based on the referrer URL.